# How to checkin the .framework deletion in SVN

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, svn

After deleting a .framework file in my XCode project, I am unable to checkin into SVN repository.

svn ci -m 'Removing unused framework.' MyFramework/test.framework
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Entry for '/Users/test/Desktop/client/src/MyFramework/test.framework' has no URL

Is there a different way to checkin .framework deletions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do an `SVN update` on the project which will restore the test.framework file in project. After that do an `SVN delete` on this file which should remove it from local copy and should mark it for removal from server as well. You can do an `SVN commit` after this.