# SVN commit and status codes

Tags: svn, commit, status

Am using SVN 1.7.17.

I deleted a file using OS command **rm** and not via **svn rm**. **svn status** is showing the status of the file as **!**, as expected. When I do **svn commit**, the file is just skipped for processing, there is no message. The other files, if any, are processed.

Is this expected behaviour? Why is SVN not stopping, considering this as an error? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A missing file that's not part of the set of files to be committed just doesn't have anything to do with the commit operation itself. After the commit it's still in `!` status.

Comment: Thanks. I remember seeing error like `codesvn: Commit failed (details follow): svn: Entry for 'xxx' has no URL` before. On what condition such an error could be expected?

Comment: Saw this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946656/how-to-checkin-the-framework-deletion-in-svn)